# How to create an array of arrays from another array filtering it by a specific key of the subarrays?

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have following array of arrays:

```
$array = [
    [A,a,1,i],
    [B,b,2,ii],
    [C,c,3,iii],
    [D,d,4,iv],
    [E,e,5,v]
];
```

From this one, I would like to create another array where the values are extract only if the value of third key of each subarray is, for example, greater than 3.

I thought in something like that:

```
if $array['2'] > 3){
    $new_array[] = [$array['0'],$array['2'],$array['3']];
}
```

So in the end we would have following new array (note that first keys of the subarrays were eliminate in the new array):

```
$new_array = [
    [D,4,iv],
    [E,5,v]
];
```

In general, I think it should be made with  foreach, but on account of my descripted problem I have no idea how I could do this. Here is what I've tried:

```
foreach($array as $value){
    foreach($value as $k => $v){
        if($k['2'] > 3){
            $new_array[] = [$v['0'], $v['2'], $v['3']];
        }
    }
}
```

But probably there's a native function of PHP that can handle it, isn't there?

Many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: to filter you would use `array_filter`, and to extract the values `0, 2, 3`, you would use `array_map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you to use `array_map()` & `array_filter()`. Example:

```
$array = [
    ['A','a',1,'i'],
    ['B','b',2,'ii'],
    ['C','c',3,'iii'],
    ['D','d',4,'iv'],
    ['E','e',5,'v']
];

$newArr = array_filter(array_map(function($v){ 
    if($v[2] > 3) return [$v[0], $v[2], $v[3]];
}, $array));

print '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
print '</pre>';
```

Reference:

- [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 0):

In the first foreach, $v is the array you want to test and copy.
You want to test $v[2] and check if it match your condition.

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($array as $v) {
    if($v[2] > 3) {
        $new_array[] = [$v[0], $v[2], $v[3]];
    }
}
```